# Trying to pass an array with variable size and it's not working properly

Tags: c

I am having problems accessing a matrix and vector with variable size using malloc() realloc() functions in a subalgorithm. I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work.

```
int main()
{
    char nombre[50];
    sprintf(nombre,"data.txt");
    int **red;
    int *links;
    int i, j, colSize;

    links  = (int*)malloc(Nred*sizeof(int));
    red = (int**)malloc(Nred*sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0; i<Nred; i++)
    {
        red[i]=(int*)malloc(1*sizeof(int));
    }

    LeeRed(*red, *links, Nred, nombre, &colSize);

}

void LeeRed (int ***mat, int **links, int nNodes, char *nombre, int *colSize)
{
    int i, j, maxSize, nodo1, nodo2;
    FILE *f, *g;

    f=fopen(nombre,"rt");
    g=fopen("matrizPrueba.txt", "w");
    maxSize=0;

    /// Number of links per node starts at 0
    for(i=0; i<nNodes; i++)
    {
        *links[i]=0;
    }
    //...
 
}
```

Comment: "[D]oesn't seem to work” is not a problem description. Edit the question to provide a [mre], including source code that other people can copy, compile, and run; sample input that reproduces the problem; observed output; and the output you desire instead. Or, if you are getting an error message from the compiler, show the full text of that. Also choose one language, C or C++, and delete the tag for the other.

Comment: Looks like you confused Value of (`*`) with adress-of(`&`) in `LeeRed(*red, *links, Nred, nombre, &colSize);`.

Comment: Your function doesn't seem to use `mat` so that would be the problem... If you want a better answer than that, maybe actually post the problematic code? "Doesn't work" isn't a problem description.

Comment: Also if you want mysterious bugs, then whatever you do don't check the result of fopen! Doing so would immediately pin-point bugs, we can't have that. Now what does `"rt"` mean?

Comment: Seing `***` is usually a bad sign. Also you should probably be calling `LeeRed(&red, ...)` to bump from `**` to `***`.

Comment: never... never cast the return value of `malloc(3)`.  It is a legacy use that was unavoidable before ansi c but used now is more error prone than anything else.  Don't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, `*` is the **dereference** operator, not the create reference operator. When you pass your matrix and links to your function, you should use `&` instead. For example:

```c
LeeRed(&red, &links, Nred, nombre, &colSize);
```

This will make all of your types match. I would be shocked if your compiler didn't warn you about this (if it's not, try recompiling with `-Wall`). That being said, you really shouldn't be passing a pointer to your matrix unless you plan on modifying *the pointer to your matrix*. You might want to do this if you were planning on reallocating the matrix for some reason, but in the function above just make your life easier and pass the pointers by value. So change your function signature to:

```c
void LeeRed (int **mat, int *links, int nNodes, const char *nombre, int *colSize);
```

Also, when you access an array with a pointer, you do not need to dereference it first, so you can use `links[i]` instead of `*links[i]`. And be careful with your allocations, right now you have an `Nredx1` matrix allocated, but if you reallocate any of those columns without freeing them, you'll have a memory leak on your hands. Be sure to free everything you allocate (from the bottom up, calling `free(red)` will **not** free the columns, you must do those individually).

I'm also not sure what the `links` variable is intended to do, but it may be redundant if you're just trying to read into a matrix. I can't help you any further without more context.

Answer (score 2):

The types of the first two parameters don't match what you're passing in.

`red` has type `int **` and `links` has type `int *`, and you're passing `*red` and `*links` which have types `int *` and `int` respectively.  This differs from the `int ***` and `int **` types that your function is expecting for these parameters.

You're also calling the function before it's been defined or declared, so it has an implicit declaration of `int LeeRead()` which doesn't match the actual definition.

You should pass these two parameters directly without dereferencing:

```
LeeRed(red, links, Nred, nombre, &colSize);
```

Change the parameter types to match:

```
void LeeRed (int **mat, int *links, int nNodes, char *nombre, int *colSize)
```

Change how these two parameters are used in the function accordingly, and move the function's definition to above `main`.